# How to enable breadcrumbs both Classic and Modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi is there any way to enable/put breadcrumbs to SharePoint online site both classic and modern experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classic experience you can create a custom master page and place your breadcrumbs and select it as the master for your site.

For modern experience we don't have the option of master page Or the script editor webpart. So only way is to go for SPFx.

You can find an example here but not sure how useful it would be

https://www.eliostruyf.com/sharepoint-framework-breadcrumb-extension-sample-available/

Thanks.

Regards,
Sukumar MS

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the below blog for the breadcrumb on classic and moderns site.
[breadcrumb on sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228971/breadcrumb-on-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 0):

To enable breadcrumbs you have to modify the master page from :

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="false"
        runat="server"
```

to :

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="false"
        runat="server"
```

https://www.brightwork.com/blog/restore-navigate-up-on-sharepoint-2013#.WsL3b-QUkeE

Or using JS link :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19713.sharepoint-2013-folder-navigationbreadcrumb.aspx

For new experience mode , seems there is no simple way .