# How to add breadcrumbs to SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, breadcrumb

Are breadcrumbs an option in SharePoint 2019 on-prem?  I cannot find any information on how to add breadcrumbs to SharePoint 2019.

Anyone!?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2019 does not have a built-in breadcrumb navigation feature. If you want to have it, you will need customized solution for it.

Similar question answered here:[How to enable breadcrumbs both Classic and Modern experience](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239027/how-to-enable-breadcrumbs-both-classic-and-modern-experience)