# Navigation doesnt appear in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, global-navigation, top-link-bar, breadcrumb

I have the rootsitecollection  -  Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSite

Subsite 1 -  Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSIte/SubSite1

And I have a subsite within Subsite 1 - Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSite/SubSite1/SubSite2

When I am at the Subsite2 the top navigation gives a link of the root site collection and not the Subsite1

How do I make the navigation show Subsite1, as I could only see the name of the rootsite.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When go to Site Settings -> Navigation Settings. You can see global navigation if you select check box `Display the same navigation items as the parent site` as shown in screenshot, then it will show you parent site navigation
  [image]

Let's talk about your scenario.

1. You have **root site collection** like this `Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSite`
2. Then you have **Subsite 1** inside root site collection - `Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSIte/SubSite1`
3. Inside **Subsite 1** you have **Subsite2** - `Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/RootSite/SubSite1/SubSite2`

So, your **Subsite2** navigation come form parent site **Subsite 1** and your **Subsite 1** navigation come from **root site collection**. basically you **Subsite2** navigation come from **root site collection**

Answer (score 1):

I mean it calls "breadcrumbs".

Use methods from this answer - [breadcrumb on sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228971/breadcrumb-on-sharepoint-online?answertab=votes#tab-top)